# How to maintain stored procedure changes in version control?

Tags: svn, stored-procedures

What is the best way of tracking changes in a stored procedure? My team has multiple members working on same database and anyone can change in business logic, create or delete a stored procedure. Sometimes a single experimental change is breaking down or need extra time for digging out the problem.

Is there any reliable system that can be used for this purpose? If there multiple, which one is the best one.